# Adding doors in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, joint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to add doors to the world that I have created in Gazebo. Basically I have modelled the entire house with furnitures and without doors. I want to add doors now. My plan is, for each door

1. Create an hinge - cylinder of radius 0.1 and length 0.2
2. Door that partially covers the hinge (as in real world).
3. A revolute joint along z axis at the intersection.

This is the code I use

```
<robot name="Work_room_door">
  <link name="hinge">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 1.125"/> 
      <mass value="0.5" />
      <inertia  ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="100.0"  iyz="0.0"  izz="1.0" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 1.125" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.2" radius="0.05"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <link name="door">
     <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0.2 1.125"/> 
      <mass value="5.0" />
      <inertia  ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="100.0"  iyz="0.0"  izz="1.0" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0.2 1.125" rpy="0 0 1.57" />
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.4 .1 2.2"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="door_hinge" type="revolute">
    <parent link="hinge"/>
    <child link="door"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0.225 1.125"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit effort="15.0" lower="-1.57" upper="1.57" velocity="1"/>
  </joint>

</robot>
```

When I run the command

```
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=door.urdf gui:=True
```

When I control the joint using gui that comes up, the door does not swivel around the hinge. Rather, it is still without motion.
Please, help me with this. How can I make the door swivel around the hinge ? or is there any other method to do it ?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38018/adding-doors-in-gazebo/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1363 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-01-07**:
was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

seems to work as-is for me (axes may be off, but I'm not sure what you're going for).  do you get any global status errors when rviz starts?

---

Originally posted by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) with karma: 235 on 2012-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0